# Automate the Installation of different WCF Services

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf, deployment

I want to have a design to automate the installation of different services I have.
Currently all my services on the client machine are installed separately. But I want to create one WPF UI that show the installation progress of all the services.
When service A is done installing I want to continue with B and C with progress bar showing the status.

For example:
I have WCF service A:
It has its own installer  and all the dlls

I have WCF service B:
It has its own installer and all the dlls

I have WCF service C:
It has its own installer and all the dlls

What is the best approach to having one UI with a text box for the folder location, install , uninstall button and progress bar?

Thank you.

Comment: Are the services in the same project or solution? How do you currently create your installations?

Comment: @CodeCaster the services are in a separate project. I didn't write the installer but each project/service has its own installer.

Comment: What kind of installer?